# daterangepicker needs double tap selecting dates in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I've been working with this library: https://www.daterangepicker.com/ (daterangepicker for JQuery), but I've encountered a strange behaviour while using the date picker on mobile devices.

The problem is that I need to double click the same date otherwise the date wont be selected. For example if I want to select dates between 04.12.2022 and 04.30.2022 I need to click 04.12.2022 cell twice if I want to select It.

I'd expect to click the date only once, but I cannot find any way to fix this.

Maybe I've some misconfiguration I need to fix.
Is there anyone with the same problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I just tried the date range picker demo on Android and it worked as expected, i.e., no double clicking required.  So you may want to compare your configuration values to that in the demo code. And without posting your code here it might be impossible for anyone to offer a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.